# how to prevent filter to make empty array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function addSelected(id) {
        var feedFound = false;
        var selList = [] ;
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.feeds.length; i++) {
            if (vm.feeds[i].id == id) {
                if (vm.rationList.length > 0) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < vm.rationList.length; j++) {
                        if (vm.feeds[i].id == vm.rationList[j].id) {
                            feedFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!feedFound) {
                    selList.push(vm.feeds[i]);
                    vm.feeds[i] = vm.feeds.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.id === vm.feeds[i].id;

                    });
                }
                feedFound = false;
            }
        }
        var li = [];
        angular.copy(selList, li);
        for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            vm.rationList.push(li[i]);
        }
        vm.rationListSafe = vm.rationList;
    }
```

**This is how i add elements from one list to another with filtering. The problem is, for each filtered element, I get back an empty array. Is there anyway I can solve this?**

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to solve with that code?

Comment: There is a usecase when i add element to another list, and then I can remove it. When I remove that element, it should be back to its previous position with unshift method. and it works, but just displays an empty element. I hope you understood now

Comment: can u add data to test..

Comment: Sorry, its not possible

Comment: ```vm.feeds[i] = vm.feeds.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.id === vm.feeds[i].id;

                    });``` seems here issue.. sould not be ..` vm.feeds = vm.feeds.filter((item) => item.id === feed.id);`

Comment: add data, json that u are working with hard to get the logic from this code.

Comment: Can you format this, I didn't quite understand what you meant

Comment: `vm.feeds[i] = vm.feeds.filter(function(item) { return item.id === vm.feeds[i].id; });` seems here issue.. sould not be ..`vm.feeds = vm.feeds.filter((item) => item.id === feed.id);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for only one item in your array, use find() instead of filter()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

PS: find may return null so you should always null-check

Example:

```
const foundItem = vm.feeds.find(function(item) {
                    return item.id === vm.feeds[i].id;
                });

if (foundItem) {
    vm.feeds[i] = foundItem
}
```

Comment: This is a good method, but the reason why I use filter is to temporarily remove element I previously clicked on and it should be back to its position later. This doesn't help me now

Comment: there is no difference in ur method and this..@ChampagneSupernova can u check logic..

Comment: find only grabs the first Element it finds. If you get nothing back, you removed the other elements right?

Comment: There is the difference. With filter, clicking on element it moves from list 1 to list 2, and its no longer beeing displayed in list1. With find, elements stays in list 1 and is also now visible in list 2. I don't need it to be visible 2x

Comment: Filter muteates an array. Find doesn't.

What do you want the code to do? Because you asked how to prevent filter from returning an empty array?

Comment: To move element from  list1 to list2 / list2 to list1 might be the answer. I thought filtering will solve this, but I guess it just made it more complicated

Comment: I think you should look into: findIndex and splice / slice.
You have all the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex